# Web Component Input radio not in a group

Tags: input, web-component, radio-group

I have the WC `<m-form>` witch is the wraper for my form and the input fields.
In the renderHTML() of m-form i do this:

```
renderHTML() {
    this.loadChildComponents().then(children => {
      Array.from(this.root.querySelectorAll('input'))
        .filter(i => i.getAttribute('type') != "hidden").forEach(input => {
          const label = this.root.querySelector(`label[for=${input.getAttribute("name")}]`)
          const aInput = new children[0][1](input, label, { namespace: this.getAttribute('namespace') || ''})
          aInput.setAttribute('type', input.getAttribute('type'))
          input.replaceWith(aInput)
        })
    })
  }
```

This wraps `<input>` and `<label>` in an `<a-input>` WC. 
But when I want to do the same with

```
<input type="radio" id="gender1" name="gender" value="herr">
<label for="gender1">Herr</label>
<input type="radio" id="gender2" name="gender" value="frau">
<label for="gender2">Frau</label>
```

they are not in a group.

What can i do to get them grouped together but also in the `<a-input`>?

Here is the Code on the site and what got rendered out.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you use the [< >] button in the editor and add a working SO snippet, tnx

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman i can't add a snippet, but i added two screenshots. I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shadowDOM encapsulates CSS, HTML **and behavior**

Both you inputs are in shadowDOM. That is like putting them into 2 **different** IFRAMEs.
They have no clue another input exists

- Remove shadowDOM (recommended)
- or, loads more work, add Events to make the inputs communicate with each other